# Lock Screen Volume Control with CCL and without CCL

Tags: android, volume, lockscreen

I can listen volume level in my VolumeService. This service listen to volume level in background.
My problem is: I can't control volume in lock screen.
I tried two different ways for volume control

**First Way with CCL**
Application Class:

```
public class CastApplication extends Application {

    private static String APPLICATION_ID;
    public static final double VOLUME_INCREMENT = 0.03;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        APPLICATION_ID = getString(R.string.app_id);
        // initialize VideoCastManager
        VideoCastManager.initialize(this, APPLICATION_ID, VideoCastControllerActivity.class, null).
                setVolumeStep(VOLUME_INCREMENT).enableFeatures(VideoCastManager.FEATURE_NOTIFICATION |VideoCastManager.FEATURE_LOCKSCREEN |
                VideoCastManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RECONNECT | VideoCastManager.FEATURE_CAPTIONS_PREFERENCE |VideoCastManager.FEATURE_DEBUGGING);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private VideoCastManager mCastManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoCastManager.checkGooglePlayServices(this);
        mCastManager = VideoCastManager.getInstance();
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this,VolumeService.class);
        startService(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (mCastManager.onDispatchVolumeKeyEvent(event, CastApplication.VOLUME_INCREMENT)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**Second way without CCL (with RRC)** 
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ContentObserver mSettingsContentObserver;
    RemoteControlClient remoteControlClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
        RemoteControlClientCompat mRemoteControlClientCompat = new RemoteControlClientCompat(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0,intent, 0));
        RemoteControlHelper.registerRemoteControlClient(mAudioManager,mRemoteControlClientCompat);
        remoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient((PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0,intent, 0)));
        MediaRouter.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).addRemoteControlClient(remoteControlClient);
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this,VolumeService.class);
        startService(i1);
    }
}
```

**Service and ContentObserver are same for both way**

VolumeService:

```
public class VolumeService extends Service {
    ContentObserver mSettingsContentObserver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mSettingsContentObserver = new SettingsContentObserver(this, new Handler());
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true,mSettingsContentObserver);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mSettingsContentObserver);
    }
}
```

ContentObserver:

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    int previousVolume;
    Context context;

    public SettingsContentObserver(Context c, Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        context = c;
        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        previousVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING); 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        int delta = previousVolume - currentVolume;
        if (delta > 0) {
            Log.i("MyService", "Volume is down");
            previousVolume = currentVolume;
        } else if (delta < 0) {
            Log.i("MyService", "Volume is up");
            previousVolume = currentVolume;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:name="com.yns.volumelock.CastApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.remotecontrol.VideoIntentReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.toggleplayback" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.stop" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.toggleplayback" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.stop" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.notificationvisibility" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.reconnection.ReconnectionService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.tracks.CaptionsPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.yns.volumelock.VolumeService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
    </application>
```

Comment: Does CastVideos-android sample app work fine for you? That uses CCL and should enable changing volume from lock screen as well. It may also depend on your phone and the android version you are running; what is the phone and what android version is there?

Comment: I tried CastVideos-android sample app on Samsung 6 Edge(5.0) , Samsung Corby Pro(4.1). But it didn't work :( Initialize to VideoCastManager and make defination in manifest file (like my code sample) is enough for Lock Screen volume control in CCL?

Comment: If CastVideos-android doesn't provide volume control on those devices, then it means that CCL cannot do that for those devices. Try Google Play Music on those devices and see how it behaves.

Comment: Google Play Music provide volume control on those devices. Also i tried open source music player.( Vanilla Music Plaer, Jams Music Player) They can volume control on lock screen too. I checked their code but their service layer is soo long. There is just video which can play in CastVideos-android sample app. Generally videos are not playing when they running in background.(they paused when we push to home button). Please forgive me if i am wrong. Maybe CastVideos sample doesnt work because of this. Could you tell me to is there any wrong or incomplate part in my code? i can try another device